# Nothing happen inside of an async function (send request with easysoap)

Tags: node.js, request

I am new in node.js, and I am experimenting things since a few days already.
Today, I have tried to send a XML request to an API, with the use of easysoap-request.
It worked perfectly, but I would have had to create an XML file for each different query, so I tried with easysoap. Here my code:

```html
const EasySoap = require('easysoap');
console.log("test");
(async () => {

    const params = {
        host    : 'https://comeapi.com',
        path    : '/dir/soap',
        wsdl    : '/dir/wsdl',
        headers: [{
            'user-agent': 'Request-Promise',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        }]
    }

    var soapClient = EasySoap(params);

    soapClient.call({
        method    :'one_methode',
        attributes: {
            xmlns: 'https://someapi.com'
        },
        params: {
            'api' : {
                'authentication' : {
                    'login' : 'mylogin',
                    'password' : 'mypassword'
                },
                'params' : {
                    'another_params' : {
                        'name' : 'Brian',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).then((callResponse) => {
        console.log(callResponse.data); // response data as json
        console.log(callResponse.body); // response body
        console.log(callResponse.header);  //response header
    }).catch((err) => { 
        throw new Error(err);
    });
    console.log("test2");
});
console.log("test3");
```

When I'm starting my file with the node command, it's only shows me "test" and "test 3" in the terminal, instead of the response of the API.
I do not understand the problem in my program because I have already used the "(async () => {" function in previous programs, and that rather well worked.

Thanks for you're help. ^^

Edit: I added the missing part in my code and now there is something new. It's an error, and I don't understand it...

(node:10264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: no wsdl/xml response
    at soapClient.call.then.catch (C:\Users\user\Documents\src\script.js:40:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:10264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Is this a problem with the .catch() ? Can someone explain me ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only defined but never called. Call your function at the end of the definition

```
(async () => {
    ....

    console.log("test2");
})(); // call this function by adding this parenthesis
```

This is called a IFFY(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) function in javascript

---

If you don't want to use a IFFY name your function and call it, like this

```
const f = async () => {
    ....

    console.log("test2");
}

f()
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the missing part, but now an error occurred. I have edited my questions.

Comment: Hi @Piko Welcome to Stackoverflow. But you should not edit question to another question when you got an answer. Please refer this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question. I believe that will require another question, Create new question and ask your new question

Answer (score 0):

Your async function needs to be called. Currently you are only declaring a function. To execute it, you need to replace the line before `console.log("test3");` by `})();`

Comment: Thanks, I added the missing part, but now an error occurred. I have edited my questions.